# Python script to convert po file to localized json

Tags: python

I need python script to convert po file to localized json.

Answer (score 0):

you might start here http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html and here http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

http://jsgettext.berlios.de/ contains a .po to json converter (p.erl) - for python you can use [polib](http://code.google.com/p/polib/) to access .po file contents and transform as desired